# Deploy a nodejs excel addin as a pkg/exe

Tags: exe, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, yeoman-generator

I have created an excel addin using yeoman generator and i would like to distribute this addin as a downloadable pkg/exe.
I came across few ways to publish and deploy office addin (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/publish)
but is there any other ways to share and publish my addin to users.

Answer (score 0):

The only method I know of that's not listed in the article you linked to is described in this blog post: https://theofficecontext.com/2020/03/23/web-add-in-side-loader-tool/.

Comment: Thank you Rick for your response!. I will try that.